# How to check if array is a min heap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

I have the following array. How can I check whether the array containing n elements is a **min heap?** 
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157159/algorithm-for-checking-if-an-array-with-n-elements-is-a-minimum-heap  Refer this.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::is_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_heap)?

Comment: The children of node i are at 2i and 2i+1. So verify a[2i] >= a[i] and a[2i+1] >= a[i] because that's the heap property: children are at least as large as their parents.

Comment: @Gene seems easier to me to start at the end and confirm that `a[i] >= a[i/2]` for all `i > 1`, decrementing `i` as you go.  That way you don't have to create two potential child indices and check both for being in-bounds.

Answer (score 5):

Since your index starts from 1, (index 0 contains 0 - why?), you can determine the index of a given node's children as follows:

- Let the index of the given node be `i`
- Index of `i`'s left child: `2i`
- Index of `i`'s right child: `2i + 1`

Thus for each node, you can easily check that both children are greater than the node itself.

Comment: Some people like to put the root at index 1. They say it's for performance reasons (eliminates an extra add when computing the left child, and removes a subtract when computing the parent), but I've done the performance comparison: no meaningful difference. The drawback is that it causes uncounted fencepost errors among C-like language programmers. I think the primary reason people do it is because Sedgewick wrote an Algorithms book in 1983, and all his examples were in Pascal, with 1-based arrays. C translations of his Pascal examples are prevalent even today.

Answer (score 3):

[`is_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_heap) is a great suggestion. You just need to use proper comparator. And you can even use it with your 1-based indexing with iterators, effortlessly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0, 5, 9, 11, 14, 18, 19 };
    std::cout << std::is_heap(
      v.begin()+1, // off by 1
      v.end(),
      std::greater<int>() // std::less is used by default for max-heap
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The familiar Breadth First Search (BFS) can also be applied to check whether the tree is a minimum/maximum heap or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

int main() {
    int tree[] = {5, 9, 11, 14, 18, 19, 21, 33, 17, 27};
    int size = 10;
    std::queue <int> q;
    q.push(0);
    bool flag = true;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        int x = q.front();
        q.pop();
        int left = 2*x+1, right = 2*x+2;  // 0-based indexing used here
        if(left < size) {    // check if left child exists or not.
            q.push(left);
          // check value at parent is less than child or not.
            if(tree[x] > tree[left]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(right < size) {   // check whether right child exists or not.
            q.push(right);
            if(tree[x] > tree[right]) {  // check value of parent less than child.
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        std::cout << "It is minimum heap.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not a minimum heap.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is similar as that of [wookie919](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626888/3160529).